# What is the formal, precise definition of area (and that of volume) in geometry?

Tags: geometry, definition, volume, area

Note: I am asking two questions. Replace "area" by "volume" with appropriate adjustments to get the second question

Hello everyone. I am studying mathematics in college and I am trying to find the formal definition of the notion "area" in geometry. What is area? I can understand it when the sides involved are integers, like when the side is 3, we have nine 1x1 grids, so the area is 9 if we think of area as the number of "unit grids". Maybe we can also define area for squares with rational sides in the same vein, but this is not a good way of thinking because how to define the area of a square of side PI or an irrational number for example?

Please give me a formal definition of area. I am looking for the most precise definition. I am not finding any results on the internet. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure

Comment: @PraiseExistence I know! This is how I like to think about it. But how do people talk about areas and volumes in classical geometry? This is what puzzles me

Comment: By classical geometry do you mean Euclidean geometry?

Comment: @M10687 yes....

Comment: I doubt Euclid ever defined area.  In fact, as far as I know there was no truly precise definition until the late 19th century.

Comment: @user00000 classical geometry? The Lebesgue measure on a subset of $R^n$ is the most fundamental definition I know of, at least if you take set theory to be your foundation.

Comment: @PraiseExistence yes but I mean how did mathematicians find areas and volumes of shapes before the notions of Lebesgue measure was established

Comment: @user00000 that seems like a math history question that I don't know the specific answer to

Comment: In other words, how was area defined in Hilbert's axiomatization of Euclidean geometry?

Comment: If you already know about Lebesgue measure theory, then why are you asking a question you already know the answer to? Unless you want to rephrase your question as a historical one.

Comment: I disagree that this is a historical question, it's just a question about understanding the axiomatic development of Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I find your suggestion that the ancient Greeks did not have a good notion of area quite remarkable. Have you even flicked through the table of contents of Euclid's Elements? Have you heard of Archimedes' method of exhaustion?

Comment: I imagine reading Lebesgue's thesis *Intégrale, longueur, aire* would provide an answer, since Lebesgue probably gives motivation in it, comparing with classical work. Don't underestimate the value of reading original literature.

Comment: I see several people saying something to the effect that (1) Euclid leaves area undefined, and therefore (2) there is some lack of rigor in Euclid's treatment of area. #1 is true and #2 is false. All mathematical theories have some undefined notions. The Lebesgue measure is not some kind of magic solution to the problem, and it's irrelevant unless you're interested in the areas of pathological point-sets. The point-set treatment of geometry is a whole different approach and is  alien to Euclid's approach.

Comment: See pages 38-47 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/160/Hilbert.pdf) for Hilbert's definition of area.

Comment: As for Euclid, he uses the word "equal" for congruent figures but also for figures with the same area, it is to the reader to decide which is the case. See [this](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI35.html) for instance.

Comment: @RobArthan Euclid's Book V, Def. 5 (encapsulating Eudoxus's theory of proportion) requires the construction of equimultiples and their pairwise comparison in respect of magnitude. For line segments, Book I, Prop. 3 enables comparison (by means of Common Notion 5) and construction of equimultiples; so the application of Eudoxus's theory to line segments is clear. However, it is not clear to me what Euclid had in mind for the comparison and construction of equimultiples of regions, as seems to be required to give area a precise *meaning*, never mind that values can be *calculated* by exhaustion.

Comment: (Continued.) It only seems to be possible to apply Book V, Def. 5 (Eudoxus's definition of equal ratios) directly to the areas of *squares*, and even doing that seems to require the use of Book I, Prop. 47 (Pythagoras's theorem) in order to enable the areas of two (or more) squares to be 'added', with the result itself being the area of a square, and so capable of being compared directly with the areas of other squares. Even the application of the theory to polygonal areas in general seems to require an extension to the definition, which is never clearly spelled out. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: Archimedes came after Euclid, so it is unsurprising that the method of exhaustion is not covered in the Elements. My comment was responding to Eric Wolfsey's very broad statement about pre-19th century mathematics (never mind Ancient Greek Mathematics) and that is what I was objecting to.

Comment: @RobArthan In honour of Book X, Prop. 1, as we're exhausting the space for comments, I shall make this comment half the length of my previous one! In his Historical Note to Book XII (Vol. 3 of Dover ed.), Heath writes: "Euclid was greatly indebted to Eudoxus, to whom the discovery of the method of exhaustion is attributed. The evidence for this attribution comes mainly from Archimedes." (In the same note, he gives an example of Archimedes's own "Method" in action.) I'd hoped to expand my comment into a question about Book XII, Prop. 2, but I've been distracted by another problem - maybe later.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: I look forward to your forthcoming question about this. I don't know the background to Heath's comment about Eudoxus and the method of exhaustion, but I am merely an interested amateur in the history of Greek mathematics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never underestimate the value of primitive notions! That said:

Here's one way to define area for a wide range of shapes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ without resorting to measure theory (and is arguably closer to the intuitive definition of area - but see below). First, define by fiat that the area of an $a\times b$ rectangle is $ab$. Next, we say that two shapes have the same area if we can cut one shape into finitely many pieces by finitely many cuts, and rearrange those pieces through finitely many rigid motions to get the other shape. See page 2 of [this paper by Hales](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312229.pdf).

(*EDIT: the definition of area of a rectangle introduces nontrivial issues around well-definedness, see the comments by Eric Wofsey below. If we want to avoid this issue, we can just define the area of a shape to be the set of all shapes it is scissors-equivalent to.*)

Now, this approach has a couple drawbacks. First of all, it utterly fails to measure the area of non-polygons. But arguably that's fine - maybe in the context of classical Euclidean geometry, we really only care about polygons, and indeed this approach **does** successfully compute the area of every polygon: any polygon can be cut and rearranged appropriately into a rectangle. The more serious problem comes when we try to generalize to higher dimensions: it turns out that even in dimension $3$, things break down! There are polyhedra with the same volume which cannot be cut and rearranged into each other. See [Hilbert's third problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem). This can be fixed by adding more complicated operations than just the scissor operations, but things rapidly get complicated. In particular, I'm not aware of any nicely-describable version of the scissor congruence which works for $n$-dimensional polyhedra; which, in my mind, is a good argument for the naturality of Lebesgue measure.

Note that Lebesgue measure is really two separate topics: first, *outer* measure ($\mu(A)$ is the inf over all covers by boxes of the sum of the measures of the boxes involved), and second, the *algebra of measurable sets*. But this second issue can be laid aside for "classical" geometry, and what we're left with is a formal notion that - in my opinion - does a very good job of capturing the informal concept of area/volume/etc. In particular, arguments by exhaustion for calculating the area of (say) the circle feel (to me) grounded in a view of area very close to this one. I go back and forth over which (scissors or measure) corresponds better to the "pre-theoretic" notion of area/volume/etc (and even over whether there *is* such a notion in the first place in any meaningful sense!). Right now, I fall very slightly on the scissors side, but that may change.

Comment: Actually, you don't need anything more than scissors-congruence if you take the theory of real numbers as given.  You can't prove directly when two polyhedra have the same value, but you can bound the volume of any polyhedron above and below (by sandwiching it between unions of tiny cubes, for instance) and thus uniquely determine volumes of all polyhedra.

Comment: A difficulty with the scissors-congruence approach that you're glossing over is proving that it's well-defined.  That is, how do you know you can't get two different areas for the same polygon by cutting it up in different ways?  If you're treating geometry axiomatically and taking area as a primitive notion, you can just assume this as an axiom.  But in a modern context where we model geometry within some broader foundation for mathematics, this is a nontrivial theorem to prove.

Comment: @EricWofsey I mean, the right way to define area via scissors-congruence is to say that the area of a polygon is the set of all polygons it is scissors-congruent to. Now there's no problem of well-definedness; the fact that this corresponds to a map to $\mathbb{R}$, of course, is a nontrivial theorem. My point wasn't that these results are easy, just that the underlying concept is different from, and in certain ways more concrete (*not* simpler) than, that of outer measure.

Comment: Right--I just felt like this needed to be pointed out since the way you wrote it in the answer seemed to be starting with a map to $\mathbb{R}$ (for instance, since you define area of rectangles using multiplication).

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, yes, that was sloppy of me. I've added a note.

Comment: It's worth noting that even the ancients used the last idea, in the form of the method of exhaustion! e.g. in the famous argument for relating the area of a circle to its perimeter and radius.

Comment: @Hurkyl Indeed, I mention exhaustion in the last paragraph.

Comment: There is still a problem of well-definedness: you need to prove that the same equivalence class does not contain two rectangle with $ab \neq cd$. Or, equivalently, that there is more than one equivalence class, which would make the whole theory trivial.

Comment: "There are polyhedra with the same volume which cannot be cut and rearranged into each other." But the converse is still true, right? That is, all polyhedra which can be cut and rearranged into one another have the same volume?

Comment: @SarcasticSully Yes, that's correct (so long as we are performing "tame" cuts - no Banach-Tarski allowed!).

Answer (score 5):

So in Euclidean geometry we have a list of axioms, together with some undefined terms. These undefined terms include: "point," "line" and "area," among others. So "area" has no precise definition in Euclidean geometry. See [here](http://academic.brcc.edu/ryanl/modules/geometry/area/area_axioms.pdf).

Comment: You are misreading the link you supplied. Your link **confirms** that Euclid's notion of area is well-defined.

Comment: Ok, I kind of messed up with that link. The real undefined term there is "region." I recalled from a geometry book I had a while ago that "area" was undefined, but in that book the term "region" had a definition if I'm remembering correctly. Good point.

Comment: @RobArthan: *Your link confirms that Euclid's notion of area is well-defined.* No, the answer is exactly right. The link gives a list of axioms about area, but it treats area as a primitive, undefined term. That's how area is treated in any approach to Euclidean geometry that is analogous to Euclid's original approach.

Comment: @Ben Crowell: the link says that the area of a unit square is unity. That (together with the other axioms) constitutes an implicit definition.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers so far have mentioned basically three kinds of **unsigned area**:

1. Scissors-congruence to compare areas. Note that this approach does not define area itself as a magnitude, unless you further add the notion of real numbers. It also fails for non-polygons unless you take limits, in which case it becomes equivalent to the next kind of area.
2. Jordan measure (equal to both the limit of the total area of grid squares contained in the figure as the grid size tends to zero and the limit of the total area of grid squares needed to contain the figure as the grid size tends to zero, if these limits are equal). Any bounded object in classical geometry has finite Jordan measure, and this is the simplest intuitive notion that the classical geometers would surely agree with, since the method of exhaustion is essentially based on the same principle. Jordan area defined is finitely-additive and hence classical geometry works as usual.
3. Lebesgue measure, which assigns a countably-additive area to some sets of the plane, and is compatible with Jordan measure whenever the Jordan measure is defined.

All of the above generalize easily to higher dimensions.

However, there is also **signed area**, which can drastically reduce the number of cases in Euclidean plane geometry when it comes to polygons. We define (signed) area of a polygon using the shoelace algorithm, and then check that $area(XP...QYR...S) = area(XP...QY) + area(YR...SX)$ (the area of a polygon is the sum of the areas of its parts), and that area is preserved when the vertices are cycled but negated when they are reversed. This allows us to handle most geometry problems without having unnecessary cases, unlike if we use unsigned area.

Nevertheless, it is not so easy to extend signed area to non-polygonal regions. We can define the (signed) area of a region bounded by a (directed) rectifiable closed curve as the limit of the area of the approximating polygon. It turns out that the limit exists, but is not so easy to prove. (To see that the condition of rectifiability cannot be dropped, note that an [Osgood curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) is a continuous closed curve with positive Lebesgue measure, and hence its interior is not Jordan measurable, which implies that the limit does not exist.)

Also, signed volume is even more troublesome to define, so it is not very useful compared to the Lebesgue measure for general sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 4):

[Jordan Measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) defines a notion of area that works for "classical geometry". I am sure that Archimedes would have been quite happy with it once he'd understood our modern obsession for Cartesian coordinate systems.

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't mentioned by the other answers. It also gives a rigorous proof for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle, which in turn is closest to the ancient Greek method of exhaustion. =)